Difficulty Mapping Subjects, Course Types, and Elearning Types from API Response
I'm working on a Python script to process course data from an API. The API provides information on various courses, including their type, subject, and type of elearning. However, I'm facing issues with mapping these values correctly.
Problem Description
I have an API response that contains course details, including courseType, subjectId, and typeOfElearning. I need to map these values to their corresponding names and understand the significance of typeOfElearning. Here’s the relevant part of the API response:
{
    "id": 4960,
    "courseType": 5,
    "subjectId": 65,
    "typeOfElearning": [
        "1",
        "3",
        "5",
        "6",
        "10"
    ],
    "date": [
        {
            "start": "September 01, 2025",
            "end": "September 26, 2025",
            "costs": "€1025",
            "registrationDeadline": "2025-08-04",
            "selectHskHwk": "HSK"
        }
    ]
}

Issues

Mapping Course Type: How should I map the courseType to its corresponding name? The courseType values are mapped as follows:

course_type_mapping = {
    1: "Bachelor's degree",
    2: "Master's degree",
    3: "PhD / Doctorate",
    4: "Cross-faculty graduate and research school",
    5: "Prep course",
    6: "Language course",
    7: "Short course"
}


Understanding Type of Elearning: The typeOfElearning field contains a list of IDs like this:

"typeOfElearning": [
    "1",
    "3",
    "5",
    "6",
    "10"
]

What do these IDs represent, and how should they be mapped?

Mapping Subjects: When trying to map the subjectId from the API response to the correct subject and its subsubjects, I encounter difficulties. Here’s the subject mapping data I have:

subject_mapping = {
    "{
  "Engineering": [
    {"id": 11, "name": "Engineering in general"},
    {"id": 12, "name": "Architecture"},
    {"id": 13, "name": "Civil Engineering"},
    {"id": 14, "name": "Electrical Engineering"},
    {"id": 15, "name": "Mechanical Engineering / Process Engineering"},
    {"id": 16, "name": "Mining, Metallurgy"},
    {"id": 17, "name": "Surveying"},
    {"id": 18, "name": "Town and Country Planning"},
    {"id": 19, "name": "Transport Engineering, Nautical Science"}
  ],
  "Languages and Cultural Studies": [
    {"id": 20, "name": "Languages and Cultural Studies in general"},
    {"id": 21, "name": "Catholic Theology"},
    {"id": 22, "name": "Civilisation Studies in the narrower sense"},
    {"id": 23, "name": "Classical Philology"},
    {"id": 24, "name": "Education"},
    {"id": 25, "name": "English Studies, American Studies"},
    {"id": 26, "name": "General and Comparative Literature and Linguistics"},
    {"id": 27, "name": "German Language and Literature (German, Germanic Languages except English)"},
    {"id": 28, "name": "History"},
    {"id": 29, "name": "Library, Documentation and Media Studies"},
    {"id": 30, "name": "Other / Non-European Languages and Cultural Studies"},
    {"id": 31, "name": "Philosophy"},
    {"id": 32, "name": "Protestant Theology"},
    {"id": 33, "name": "Psychology"},
    {"id": 34, "name": "Romance Languages"},
    {"id": 35, "name": "Slavonic, Baltic, Finno-Ugrian Studies"},
    {"id": 36, "name": "Special Education"}
  ],
  "Law, Economics and Social Sciences": [
    {"id": 37, "name": "Law, Economics and Social Sciences in general"},
    {"id": 38, "name": "Business and Economics"},
    {"id": 39, "name": "Industrial Engineering"},
    {"id": 40, "name": "Law"},
    {"id": 41, "name": "Political Science"},
    {"id": 42, "name": "Public Administration"},
    {"id": 43, "name": "Regional Studies"},
    {"id": 44, "name": "Social Science"},
    {"id": 45, "name": "Social Services"}
  ],
  "Mathematics, Natural Sciences": [
    {"id": 46, "name": "Mathematics, Natural Sciences in general"},
    {"id": 47, "name": "Biology"},
    {"id": 48, "name": "Chemistry"},
    {"id": 49, "name": "Computer Science"},
    {"id": 50, "name": "Earth Sciences (excluding Geography)"},
    {"id": 51, "name": "Geography"},
    {"id": 52, "name": "Mathematics"},
    {"id": 53, "name": "Pharmacy"},
    {"id": 54, "name": "Physics, Astronomy"}
  ],
  "Medicine": [
    {"id": 55, "name": "Medicine in general"},
    {"id": 56, "name": "Clinical, Practical Medicine (excluding Dentistry)"},
    {"id": 57, "name": "Clinical, Theoretical Medicine (including Dentistry)"},
    {"id": 58, "name": "Dentistry (Clinical, Practical)"},
    {"id": 59, "name": "Pre-clinical Medical Studies (including Dentistry)"}
  ],
  "Sport": [
    {"id": 60, "name": "Sport"}
  ],
  "Veterinary Medicine": [
    {"id": 61, "name": "Veterinary Medicine in general"},
    {"id": 62, "name": "Clinical Practical Veterinary Medicine"},
    {"id": 63, "name": "Clinical Theoretical Veterinary Medicine"},
    {"id": 64, "name": "Pre-clinical Veterinary Medicine"}
  ],
  "German Language": [
    {"id": 65, "name": "German Language Course (including Literature and Culture Studies)"},
    {"id": 66, "name": "Preparatory Course for German Language Examinations"},
    {"id": 67, "name": "Didactics of German as a Foreign Language"},
    {"id": 68, "name": "Translation and Interpretation"},
    {"id": 69, "name": "German as a Technical Language"},
    {"id": 71, "name": "German as an Academic Language"}
  ]
}

Testing Input and Expected Output
Testing Input:
courses = [
    {
        "courseType": 2,
        "subject": "Architecture",
        "date": [
            {"start": "2025-09", "end": "2026-09", "costs": 500}
        ]
    }
]


Expected Output:
{
    "date": [
        {
            "start": "September 2025",
            "end": "September 2026",
            "costs": "€500"
        }
    ],
    "courseTypeName": "Master's degree",
    "subjectName": "Engineering",
    "subSubjectName": "Architecture"
}

Original Output and Code
Original Output from API:
    {
            "id": 4960,
            "image": "/app/ip/media/cache/resolve/16_9_300px/uploads/images/image/online/5eb302e5bfd0d581357788.jpeg",
            "copyright": "Pexels",
            "courseName": "Academic Life in Leipzig \u2013 Autumn Language Course for International Researchers, Doctoral Candidates, and Students",
            "courseNameShort": "Academic Life in Leipzig \u2013 Autumn Language Course",
            "academy": "Leipzig University",
            "city": "Leipzig",
            "languages": [
                "German"
            ],
            "languageLevelGerman": [
                "A1",
                "A2",
                "B1",
                "B2",
                "C1"
            ],
            "languageLevelEnglish": null,
            "beginning": null,
            "programmeDuration": null,
            "date": [
                {
                    "start": "2025-09-01",
                    "end": "2025-09-26",
                    "costs": 1025,
                    "registrationDeadline": "2025-08-04",
                    "selectHskHwk": "HSK"
                }
            ],
            "typeCourseDate": "The date of the course has been set",
            "costString": null,
            "tuitionFees": null,
            "courseType": 5,
            "isElearning": false,
            "preparationForDegree": null,
            "preparationForSubjectGroups": null,
            "applicationDeadline": null,
            "isCompleteOnlinePossible": false,
            "badgeLabel": "",
            "financialSupport": null,
            "structuredResearch": null,
            "supportInternationalStudents": null,
            "subject": "German Language Course (including Literature and Culture Studies)",
            "typeOfElearning": [
                "1",
                "3",
                "5",
                "6",
                "10"
            ],
            "link": "/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/en/detail/4960/",
            "requestLanguage": "en"
        }

Original Code:
import requests
import json
url = "https://www2.daad.de/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/api/solr/en/search.json"
params = {
    "cert": "",
    "admReq": "",
    "langExamPC": "",
    "scholarshipLC": "",
    "langExamLC": "",
    "scholarshipSC": "",
    "langExamSC": "",
    "fos": "",
    "langDeAvailable": "",
    "langEnAvailable": "",
    "fee": "",
    "sort": "4",
    "dur": "",
    "q": "",
    "limit": "1",
    "offset": "10",
    "display": "list",
    "isElearning": "",
    "isSep": ""
}

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Not)A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"127\", \"Chromium\";v=\"127\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\""
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)

if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    print(len(data["courses"]))
    with open('./daad_data.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(response.json(), json_file, indent=4)
    print("Data saved to daad_data.json")
    # print(data)  # or process the data as needed
else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")

What I Need Help With

Mapping Course Type: How should I map the courseType to its corresponding name?
Understanding Type of Elearning: What do the IDs in typeOfElearning represent, and how should they be mapped?
Mapping Subjects: How can I ensure that subjectId is mapped correctly to the right subject and its subsubjects?
Handling Mismatches: What is the best approach to handle cases where subjectId or typeOfElearning does not match any of the
available options?

Any guidance or suggestions on improving the mapping function would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
What I Tried:

Mapped courseType values to names using a course_type_mapping dictionary.
Mapped subjectId to subject and subsubject names using subject_mapping.
Converted typeOfElearning IDs to names.
Formatted dates and costs.

What I Expected:

Accurate course type names.
Correct subject and subsubject names.
Meaningful elearning type names.
Properly formatted dates and costs.

Issue:

Some subjectId and typeOfElearning IDs do not map correctly.
Formatting of dates and costs is inconsistent.


There is no subjectId in the API response, the subject field is a string, and it's value is the "sub-subject".

The mapping issues (courseType and subjectId) are best solved using pandas merge. For your question about typeOfElearning - there's no way to tell what exactly these mean without looking at the documentation for the API you're dealing with. Once you obtain a mapping dictionary for this field, you can solve using the same approach.
import json
import pandas as pd


def generate_course_type_mapping_df(course_type_mapping: dict):
    # convert course_type_mapping to a pandas dataframe
    course_type_mapping_df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(course_type_mapping), orient='index').reset_index()
    course_type_mapping_df.columns = ['courseType', 'courseTypeName']
    return course_type_mapping_df


def generate_subject_mapping_df(subject_mapping: dict):
    # flatten subject_mapping to flattened_subject_mapping
    flattened_subject_mapping = []
    for subject, items in subject_mapping.items():
        for item in items:
            flattened_subject_mapping.append({"subjectName": subject, "subjectId": item["id"], "subSubjectName": item["name"]})

    # convert flattened_subject_mapping to a pandas dataframe
    flattened_subject_mapping_df = pd.DataFrame(flattened_subject_mapping)
    return flattened_subject_mapping_df


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # mappings
    COURSE_TYPE_MAPPING = {
        1: "Bachelor's degree",
        2: "Master's degree",
        3: "PhD / Doctorate",
        4: "Cross-faculty graduate and research school",
        5: "Prep course",
        6: "Language course",
        7: "Short course"
    }
    SUBJECT_MAPPING = {
        "Engineering": [
            {"id": 11, "name": "Engineering in general"},
            {"id": 12, "name": "Architecture"},
            {"id": 13, "name": "Civil Engineering"},
            {"id": 14, "name": "Electrical Engineering"},
            {"id": 15, "name": "Mechanical Engineering / Process Engineering"},
            {"id": 16, "name": "Mining, Metallurgy"},
            {"id": 17, "name": "Surveying"},
            {"id": 18, "name": "Town and Country Planning"},
            {"id": 19, "name": "Transport Engineering, Nautical Science"}
        ],
        "Languages and Cultural Studies": [
            {"id": 20, "name": "Languages and Cultural Studies in general"},
            {"id": 21, "name": "Catholic Theology"},
            {"id": 22, "name": "Civilisation Studies in the narrower sense"},
            {"id": 23, "name": "Classical Philology"},
            {"id": 24, "name": "Education"},
            {"id": 25, "name": "English Studies, American Studies"},
            {"id": 26, "name": "General and Comparative Literature and Linguistics"},
            {"id": 27, "name": "German Language and Literature (German, Germanic Languages except English)"},
            {"id": 28, "name": "History"},
            {"id": 29, "name": "Library, Documentation and Media Studies"},
            {"id": 30, "name": "Other / Non-European Languages and Cultural Studies"},
            {"id": 31, "name": "Philosophy"},
            {"id": 32, "name": "Protestant Theology"},
            {"id": 33, "name": "Psychology"},
            {"id": 34, "name": "Romance Languages"},
            {"id": 35, "name": "Slavonic, Baltic, Finno-Ugrian Studies"},
            {"id": 36, "name": "Special Education"}
        ],
        "Law, Economics and Social Sciences": [
            {"id": 37, "name": "Law, Economics and Social Sciences in general"},
            {"id": 38, "name": "Business and Economics"},
            {"id": 39, "name": "Industrial Engineering"},
            {"id": 40, "name": "Law"},
            {"id": 41, "name": "Political Science"},
            {"id": 42, "name": "Public Administration"},
            {"id": 43, "name": "Regional Studies"},
            {"id": 44, "name": "Social Science"},
            {"id": 45, "name": "Social Services"}
        ],
        "Mathematics, Natural Sciences": [
            {"id": 46, "name": "Mathematics, Natural Sciences in general"},
            {"id": 47, "name": "Biology"},
            {"id": 48, "name": "Chemistry"},
            {"id": 49, "name": "Computer Science"},
            {"id": 50, "name": "Earth Sciences (excluding Geography)"},
            {"id": 51, "name": "Geography"},
            {"id": 52, "name": "Mathematics"},
            {"id": 53, "name": "Pharmacy"},
            {"id": 54, "name": "Physics, Astronomy"}
        ],
        "Medicine": [
            {"id": 55, "name": "Medicine in general"},
            {"id": 56, "name": "Clinical, Practical Medicine (excluding Dentistry)"},
            {"id": 57, "name": "Clinical, Theoretical Medicine (including Dentistry)"},
            {"id": 58, "name": "Dentistry (Clinical, Practical)"},
            {"id": 59, "name": "Pre-clinical Medical Studies (including Dentistry)"}
        ],
        "Sport": [
            {"id": 60, "name": "Sport"}
        ],
        "Veterinary Medicine": [
            {"id": 61, "name": "Veterinary Medicine in general"},
            {"id": 62, "name": "Clinical Practical Veterinary Medicine"},
            {"id": 63, "name": "Clinical Theoretical Veterinary Medicine"},
            {"id": 64, "name": "Pre-clinical Veterinary Medicine"}
        ],
        "German Language": [
            {"id": 65, "name": "German Language Course (including Literature and Culture Studies)"},
            {"id": 66, "name": "Preparatory Course for German Language Examinations"},
            {"id": 67, "name": "Didactics of German as a Foreign Language"},
            {"id": 68, "name": "Translation and Interpretation"},
            {"id": 69, "name": "German as a Technical Language"},
            {"id": 71, "name": "German as an Academic Language"}
        ]
    }

    # generate mapping dfs
    course_type_mapping_df = generate_course_type_mapping_df(COURSE_TYPE_MAPPING)
    subject_mapping_df = generate_subject_mapping_df(SUBJECT_MAPPING)

    # testing input
    courses = [
        {
            "courseType": 2,
            "subjectId": 12,
            "date": [
                {"start": "2025-09", "end": "2026-09", "costs": 500}
            ]
        }
    ]
    # convert testing input to a dataframe
    courses_df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(courses))

    # merge with course_type_mapping_df
    courses_df = pd.merge(courses_df, course_type_mapping_df, on='courseType', how='left')

    # merge with flattened_subject_mapping_df
    courses_df = pd.merge(courses_df, subject_mapping_df, on='subjectId', how='left')

    # remove ID columns
    courses_df = courses_df.drop(['courseType', 'subjectId'], axis=1)

    # convert courses_df to json/dict output
    output_json = courses_df.to_json(orient='records')
    output_dict = courses_df.to_dict(orient='records')

    print(output_json)
    print(output_dict)


I tried in my code, but I still get numbers like courseType: 5 from the API. After processing the data, it gives me numbers instead of names. For example, it gives me "subject": "German Language Course (including Literature and Culture Studies)", but it doesn't give the sub-subject name. Instead, it puts the sub-subject name in the field called subject.

Why do you expect to get a different output from the API? The above solution is to modify the output from the API to suit your requirements. You need to take up issues regarding the output of APIs with the developers who built it as there is no way for us to know what APIs you're using and how they function.
